# Does foreach() work for non-numerical array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I was wondering if foreach() works when the array looks like this:

- arr_name[eggs] = something
- arr_name[pencil] = something else

Will foreach work if run as:

```
foreach(arr_name as $key => $value)
```

for they keys that have a non-numerical value ?

Comment: really was it really that hard to try it out? instead of asking here in stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes - I could have found out on my own, but searching didn't give me good enough results. So it would have taken more time than it has to for such a simple question. Also, people will find the answer here in the future, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `foreach` supports any kind of key. In your case, `$key` will be a string, `'eggs'` and `'pencil'` respectively for each item. In fact, `foreach` was intended for use with arrays that have non-numerical keys which you can't easily iterate using `for`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PHP has no real distinction between arrays with numeric vs non-numeric keys. They're all simply arrays as far as PHP is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the explanation given by BoltClock is right & i would suggest you to manually try too. You have missed $before array name in the foreach statement

foreach($arr_name as $key=>$value)
    echo $value
?>