# How do you get "IE 6 conditional comments" working?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, conditional-comments

i have this markup which works fine:

```
<div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6">
```

i am now trying to put a ie6 specific workaround so i am trying to only have this div if the browser is not IE 6.  So i want this line to hit if its IE7, 8 and firefox and chrome.  I tried this but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox or Chrome.

```
<!--[if !(IE 6)]>
    <div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6">
<![endif]-->
```

is there any "if everything but IE6" conditional comment that works in an html file ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target any IE except IE6, you use the `!` operator:

```
<!--[if !IE 6]>
    <div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6">
<![endif]-->
```

To target any IE except IE6 **as well as all other browsers**, you need special syntax to break out of the conditional comments so other browsers can read and parse the HTML inside, instead of seeing the entire block as one comment:

```
<!--[if !IE 6]><!-->
    <div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The original syntax as shown in [voyager's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423134/106224), known as *downlevel-revealed* syntax, lacks the extra comment delimiters. However, it is invalid HTML, so to maintain document validity you should use the above syntax instead.

Comment: It might be even easier to use `<!--[if lt IE 7]>`, rather than using the `!` operator. But swings and roundabouts...

Comment: @David: Don't you mean `if gte IE 7`?

Comment: @BoltClock, um, why: yes; yes, I do... =D

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I'm intrigued as to the reason for the down-vote...

Comment: @BoltClock: but not *explained*, which is the part that always irritates me. I don't *mind* being down-voted, but without explanation there's no opportunity to *learn* from it. Which is a completely wasted opportunity.

Comment: @David: I understand. At least if someone explains their downvote, I can tell if it's a good reason... or a stupid reason, like for [this other answer of mine :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352971/does-foreach-work-for-non-numerical-array-keys/4352974#4352974)

Comment: @David: Oh, he's well-known around these parts.

Comment: I was the downvoter, and did so because I figured that the close comment method BoltClock used was unneeded when there was a simpler way. I undid the downvote only because of the comment on my answer. @David: I think that going around explaining downvotes is counter productive. More times than I can count I've seen people that firmly believe that downvoting is **always** wrong. Don't pay attention to *a* downvote, unless by reading the other answers you can't understand what might be wrong. Also, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvotes+explain

Comment: @voyager, the point of a down-vote is to make the point that an answer is unhelpful. Explaining in what way the answer is unhelpful gives everyone a chance to learn, which is, surely, the point of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

What you [have to use is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed)

```
<![if !IE 6]>
  <div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6">
<![endif]>
```

Browsers other than IE see `<!--[if !IE 6]><div id="hd1" class="header headerNotIE6"><![endif]-->` as a normal comment, so they don't ever get to see the `div` inside.

Comment: While that works for IE, it causes the HTML to become invalid.

Comment: @BoltClock: it's the recommended way by MS, yet it's a valid point. Keep in mind that if you are having hacks for IE6 your code most likely won't be validating anyway.