# Don't load script in IE6 or less

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

How can I add a condition so that if a user is running IE6 or less not to load some javascript. I've tried the following, and the `<script>` doesn't load in any browser:

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
<script blah blah blah... />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if ! IE 6]>
<script blah blah blah... />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE 6]>
<script blah blah blah... />
<![endif]-->
```

Some assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
<script blah blah blah... />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The above syntax (with the extra comment delimiters) is explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423000/how-do-you-get-ie-6-conditional-comments-working/4423037#4423037).

Comment: This will be understood by IE browsers only i guess. Other browsers do not understand conditional comments.

Comment: @easwee: Please refer to the linked post.

Comment: @easwee, the `<!-->` takes care of non IE browsers as they see the comment closed..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [head.js](http://headjs.com/)? You could load that first, and wrap the actual script loading in a condition, something like:

```
<script>
if(!isIE6) {
  head.js("path/to/script1.js", "path/to/script2.js");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the double negative to exclude scripts from running on a particular IE version

```
<!-- disabled all javascript in IE6 -->
<!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    // special not IE6 stuff
</script>

<!--<![endif]-->
```

Use a simple check to run scripts only on IE6

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // special IE6 stuff
</script>

<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a read, should help.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

I've only ever used [if IE 6] before, but worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the script for IE 7 and higher.

```
<!-- [if gte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Reference.