# Safari 6 not calculating <!--[if !IE]> conditionals

Tags: html, css, safari, conditional-comments, safari6

Am I doing something incorrect here?  I have !ie conditionals, however it seems that Safari 6 (not below) is not calculating these anymore.  Has anyone experienced this?

my block:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  /* styles */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: IE conditionals are, by definition, only interpreted by IE.

Comment: Safari is not supposed to interpret that as anything special below version 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the conditional statements in their own comments using this syntax:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<style type="text/css">
  /* styles */
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Otherwise the whole thing will be treated as one giant comment block, and that should happen in any version of Safari, not just 6. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423000/how-do-you-get-ie-6-conditional-comments-working) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the IE conditional for !IE is:

```
<![if IE]>
```

It's not a comment at all because anything inside a comment is going to be hidden by a standards compliant browser.

Please do the world a favor and only use conditional comments for IE. At least it's technically standards compliant as the non-standard code is inside of a comment. The fake tag above would not validate.

Comment: It can be worked around using comment syntax, as shown in my answer and the link therein. Of course, Microsoft will always be Microsoft...